# Erro ao criar uma tabela simples Django?

Tags: python, django, servidor

[image: <code>Erro Apresentado</code>]

```
class Produtos(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nomeproduto = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    quantproduto = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, unique=True)
status = models.CharField('Status', max_length=10, default='ATIVO', blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table: str = 'usuarios'
        ordering = ('nome_produto',)
```

O principal problema é ele informar erro de identação mas eu sou cego sou iniciante na linguagem então qualquer erro óbvio me falem, por favor.

Comment: Tenha atenção que na opção **ordering** da  class Meta você usa **'nome_produto'**, isso é diferente do compo **nomeproduto** que você definiu no classe Produto, desse jeito você não está referenciar o campo, pois **nome_produto** é diferente de **nomeproduto**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei qual ferramenta você está usando para escrever o seu código, mas maior parte delas possuem um mecanismo que auxilia manter a indentação corretamente.

Para python, são 4 espaços para cada nível de indentação.

Então, ao definir a classe, sem identação. Para cada atributo, campo e etc dentro dessa classe, você precisa adicionar 4 espaços.

Caso você crie um método dentro da classe, o código desse método precisar ter, então, 8 espaços.

Com sua condição, eu recomendo um cuidado ao copiar códigos daqui ou outros lugares, pois eles podem conter espaços extras e causar erros como esse.

Recomendo a leitura do [guia do estilo escrito pela python Brasil](https://wiki.python.org.br/GuiaDeEstilo).

Answer (score 0):

> Essa deve ser a indentação correta

```
class Produtos(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nomeproduto = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    quantproduto = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField('Status', max_length=10, default='ATIVO', blank=False, null=False)
```

Outro ponto que poderá ocassionar um erro é como você declarou o nome da tabela na classe Meta. Segundo a documentação do django não é necessário especificar o tipo de dado, ficando desta forma:

```
db_table = 'usuarios'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#db-table